# What is the most Pythonic Way to Catch Thrown Library Errors From Deep Inside Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have code that looks like this:

```
# foo.py
from internallib.a import A

A.some(new_schema)
```

```
# a.py
from internallib.b import B

class A:
   @staticmethod
   def some(schema_name):
      B.thing(schema_name, other_parameter)
```

```
# b.py
import marshmallow

class B:
   @staticmethod
   def thing(schema_name, other_parameter):
      marshmallow.class_registry.get_class(schema_name)
```

Marshmallow throws an error that I'd like to catch and print nicely for the user and then exit (instead of just printing a stack trace). The specifics here are that Marshmallow throws a RegistryError when get_class is called and the schema hasn't been registered.

However, this is a completely expected condition - it's ok to TRY to add the schema, and I want to present that error to the user - think of it kind like a 'file not found' error. A stack trace feels way too low level to present.

However, `A.some()` is called in many places in the code. What's the pythonic way of doing this? My thoughts:

- Wrap the marshmallow() in a try-except, print something out and then exit()
- Go everywhere I call `A.some(new_schema)` and wrap that (it's not my preference, but if necessary)
- Something else?

Comment: It really depends on the library, in some contexts it would be good to let the error bubble up, in other contexts it would make sense to catch certain errors from external libraries and raise your own internal errors for better context into what's going wrong. It would be helpful for you to include any additional context possible.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Marshmallow - and, in this case, when trying to add an unknown schema, it fails. However, this is a completely expected condition (it's ok to TRY to add the schema, and I want to present that error to the user - something like 'file not found'). A stack trace is way too low level.

Comment: Ok, those details are good context to add to the question, so please do. The more concrete your question is the easier it is for others to understand.

Comment: Answered, but while questions such as these are ok to ask on Stack Overflow, they are more appropriate on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @pygeek when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context about what the code actually does - i.e. looks very hypothetical.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I did prompt the author to add more context to the question to avoid it being marked as vague or off topic but it doesn't seem like they want to. I'll add those links next time, thanks.

Comment: @pygeek I really appreciate it - should I move this over there?

Comment: @aronchick just update your question to include details. It doesn’t need to be actual source code from your repository, but should have more context such as marshmallow and method calls that add context not just a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Option 1 - uniform behavior for all `A.some()` callers: Wrap `B.thing()` call in `A.some()` in a `try` `except` catching very specific exceptions while using logger to log error in the `except` block prior to exiting.

Option 2 - varying behavior needed for `A.some()` callers: If you wanted varying behavior depending on the context of where A.some() is being called, then you would need to refactor to catch the same error from Option 1 and raise your own internal error named FileNotFound, which each caller to `A.some()` would be able to handle behavior individually.

Comment: Thanks! So is:
```
try:
   ...
except:
   ... 
   exit()
```

acceptable?

Comment: @aronchick as long as you’re catching specific errors—not just Exception. You also may want to log specific errors via the logger.info, which can be adapted to log to file/console via the standard logging adapter.